# show in a while loop only the records not inserted in another table

Tags: php, mysql

i have two tables, categorias and precios

in categorias im saving all the categories

in precios only a few

how do i show in a while the records missing in precios?

```
$query = $mysqli->query("select * from categorias"); //all data stored
while ($resultados = $query->fetch_array()) {  //here we show
 $m =$resultados['subcat']; //the subcats..
```

ho do i show only the categories where is not inserted in precios table?

i tried this but does not work:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("select * from categorias where subcat != '$pi'");
```

$pi is the categories inserted in precios

Comment: What are the columns in each table?

Comment: in categorias = id,topcat and subcat ,in precios id,cat,price i have inserted only 3 categories on precios and i want to show only the 6 cateories not inserted in precios

Comment: And the "cat" in precious corresponds to "subcat" in categorias?

Comment: yes  thats the relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **SUBCAT** is a **FOREGIN KEY on PRECIOS** :

```
SELECT * FROM CATEGORIAS WHERE SUBCAT NOT IN 
(SELECT ID FROM PRECIOS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE
NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM precious WHERE cat=subcat)
```